# Display Query Results Report-style

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to set up a query that will create a simple report that will show a data range over a two week period whether a cron job was scheduled or not. I have [two tables and sample data available here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db02a/5)  that I was using try and figure out a way to display the results. I have an [example of a way that would work to display the data](http://jsbin.com/fewaguxoxe/edit?html,output), except I have no clue how to get it to work.

Normally I would post the code that I was using to try and make something work, I honestly don't even know where to start. Maybe it's not possible, but I think it is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your fiddle what mean `AS 'Ran?'` and how the alias become `cronStatus`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this requires a pivot table and a possible duplicate is found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/3854195)

The following is based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968969/3854195

```
SELECT cronDate
    , COUNT(cronJobCD=1 AND cronStatus=1 OR NULL) AS BV_Conn
    , COUNT(cronJobCD=2 AND cronStatus=1 OR NULL) AS BV_Conn2
    , COUNT(cronJobCD=3 AND cronStatus=1 OR NULL) AS ConvPro
    , COUNT(cronJobCD=4 AND cronStatus=1 OR NULL) AS SalesPerson
    , COUNT(cronJobCD=5 AND cronStatus=1 OR NULL) AS NS_BV
    , COUNT(cronJobCD=6 AND cronStatus=1 OR NULL) AS NS_Feeds
FROM 
    cronStatus S
GROUP BY 
    cronDate
```